# How to use RemoteWebElement ID in findElements / findElement / isEnabled / isDisabled?

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver

I have certain special requirement, where I am capturing Response of findElement command and getting RemoteWebElement ID. I get this ID something like this:

```
String COMMAND = "findElement";
String COMMAND_PARAMS = "{using=xpath, value=//*[@id='nextAtRightOnScroll']}";

Response response =  driver.execute(COMMAND, COMMAND_PARAMS) ;
remoteWebElement = (RemoteWebElement) response.getValue();

System.out.println("==RemoteWebElement ElementID: "+remoteWebElement.getId());
```

In Chrome: `0.9358879196235208-1`

In Firefox:  `{a67fc38c-10e6-4c5e-87dc-dd45134db570}`

My question is how I can use this RemoteWebElement ID which is `remoteWebElement.getId()` to reverse `findElement`, `isDisplayed` and `isEnabled` like methods of Selenium ?

P.S.: My usecase is, I attempt to click a button using RemoteWebElement ID, now if that button is not visible and I get ElementNotVisible exception then, I want to check with `findElement`, `isDisplayed` and `isEnabled` for that Element.
I have only it's RemoteWebElement ID and not the Element ID for that element to be clicked.

Comment: so the `ID` is stored in `remoteWebElement` currently as a `RemoteWebElement` type? Couldn't you just use the normal selenium commands with `remoteWebElement` from there? I might not fully understand the question...

Comment: @mrfreester: I updated my question with P.S. section. Please check.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do things that `WebDriverWait` does for you, except in a much more complicated way. You might want to look into how you can use `WebDriverWait`, which is commonly referenced if you search for **explicit waits** in selenium, to be able to wait for an expected state before you execute selenium commands.

Comment: @mrfreester: No no no.. Actually I have information about previously run command in form of Commands and Command_Params only. I get it from Database. Now I want to replay the testcase using a sequence of Commands and Command_params. In this situation, I get RemoteWebElement ID of element, I want to check if that element is present in DOM ?

Comment: @OmSao, don't do that. These id are unique ids and not related to element and if you refresh the page and find same element the id will be different. So it makes no sense to store or reverse them for any action

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Yes, I understand that, they are dynamically generated. I am generating them dynamically.
I want to know, can I use this dynamically generated RemoteWebElement ID in findElement(s), isEnabled and isDisplayed ?
If possible, please let me know.. it will help me.

Comment: Each action is a JSON invocation in and it uses element id for invocation. So technically nothing stops you from using the ID which has been just found. But that just means implementing lower level code which selenium is already doing. So you can look at the selenium client for Java code and workout the details